# Changing font size in select change the height of his parent

Tags: html, css, select, fonts, height

I have a drop-down list with a separate button, only changing font has changed the height of the parent box.

The height of the select is 50px, if I leave the default font size, the height of the parent div is 50px.

But if I change the size of the font, the size of the parent div is equal to 50px + a few px not found in the console, the result is select and button are not in same line

Do you have any idea of ​​the problem?

```
<section class="central_row">
    <select name="name" id="list_name">
        <option value="an option">an option</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" class="next-select"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</section>  



select {
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
    background: #1b997a;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 14px;
}

button.next-select {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Here is a fiddle with the problem : [a little problem with the select](https://jsfiddle.net/gratien/o5n198jL/6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your question you want to make sure that you do not update the height of your select box. If that is correct why do you not try to update the height component in select to max-height. Something like:

```
select{
    width: 250px;
    max-height: 50px;
    border: none;
    background: #1b997a;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 14px;
}
```

What select must be doing is, inorder to fit the margins and the text, increase the height as well.

Or you could try to use this https://jsfiddle.net/q4onutso/2/

Hope this helps.

Comment: This solution not working, even if I put the size of the parent div in fixed I have these few extra pixels

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/q4onutso/ Here is my updated fiddle. Can you confirm whether this is what you want?

Comment: No, i need the select with the height of 50px

Comment: @Buck could you check this https://jsfiddle.net/q4onutso/1/ . I am having some difficulty understanding your use-case. Could you check the fiddle?

Comment: The button is 4 pixel lower of select, they are not centered  http://hpics.li/8034efd

Comment: Ah... Sorry.. A simple vertical align should work https://jsfiddle.net/q4onutso/2/ . Could you check whether this is what you want?

Comment: Yes, i found another solution but your work well to, thanks :)

Comment: Cool. Let me update it so that others can use the same solution. If you like this answer could you please upvote.

Comment: Yes no probleme :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
select{
    float:left;
}
```

And you are good to go.

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/dhavaljardosh/o5n198jL/11/

Comment: Doesn't work
I've looked if those pseudo elements could generate padding or margin, but not